# Understanding the flexible padding

Tags: css

Under the regular box model:

**Ethan Marcotte** in Responsive Webdesign, page 35, wrote:

> when setting flexible padding on a element, your context is the *width
>   of the element itself.*

Please take a look at the following example:

```css
.main-wrapper {
  width: 98%; /*960px - to give some space on the viewport*/ 
}

.box-one,
.box-two {
    width: 44.791666666667%; /* 430 / 960 */
    float: left;
    margin: 30px 0 20px 0;
    padding: 2.083333333333%; /* padding should be 20px*/
    text-align: center;
}

.box-one {
    margin-right: 2.083333333333%; 
    /*margin is relative to the container (here 960px), so:
      20/960
    */
    background-color: red;
}

.box-two {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrapper">

  <div class="box-one">
    <p>box one here</p>
  </div>

  <div class="box-two">
    <p>box two here</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

My question is:

According to what is wrote on that book, the padding setting of:
shoudn't NOT be correct (but it is!).

```
padding: 2.083333333333%;
```

Instead:
We should take into consideration *the element width itself* and that is `430px`. But IF we use that value as context, we get 4.x %.

What am I NOT getting here?

Comment: If you don't understand my question, I can make an effort to clarify. Just drop a comment. Thank you.

Comment: The main wrapper is the element, no? Nested divs are constrained by the parent div.

Comment: could you explain what you mean by "context" please?

Comment: Gary Hayes, as far as I was able to understand, according to my reading, the *element itself*, should NOT be the `main-wrapper`, but `.box-one` and `.box-two` specifically?

Comment: @web-tiki: The context, according to my understanding of the author writtings, is the value that you have as a reference. ie.
If you wish to convert your `margin` of 20px to be flexible, on a given layout, you should divide that value by your container width. On that case, the `container width` is the `context`.

Comment: Ok this wasn't clear to me. after reading a few times I think I have understood what you mean, tell me if I'm wrong : you are trying to find the base value to calculate the padding and what that book tells you is that the base should be the width of one of those child block?

Comment: @web-tiki: The book says that the width that I should consider is the width of the element itself, meaning, the width of the element we wish to apply the padding to. So, I believe it is as you say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't read the book you refer to and it is difficult to guess what it says as I don't have the context around the sentence you quote.

This said, if you reffer to the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#padding-properties) about percentage padding calculation :

> percentage
>
> The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of
>   the generated box's containing block, [...]

So the percentage is calculated according to the **parent's width** and therefore the  `2.083333333333%` value is correct.

Comment: Book author replied and said it will fix that on the second revision of the book. :)